# SAS Count Frequency under some conditions

Tags: sas

| ID | GET_DRUG | HOSP | DATE | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | H111 | H111 | 2021/12/31 | 3 |
| A | H112 | H112 | 2022/1/10 | 4 |
| A | H110 | H110 | 2022/1/13 | 5 |
| A | D110 | H110 | 2022/1/14 | 6 |
| A | D111 | H110 | 2022/1/16 | 3 |
| A | H112 | H112 | 2022/1/23 | 4 |
| A | D113 | H110 | 2022/1/30 | 5 |
| A | D114 | H110 | 2022/2/13 | 5 |

[image: Data is order by Date.]

[![
Step(1).Trying to do calculation like this, the initial character of variable "GET_DRUG" is "D" then calculating days with above each row but only keeping DATE_DIFFERENCE<=15 days records.

Step(2).Count distinct variable "HOSP" value and sum variable "QTY" OF Step(1) result.

Step(3).Count frequency of Step(2) result if HOSP NUM>=2 AND QTY_SUM>=10. ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/029Xl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/029Xl.png)

Final answer is "2" including "2021/12/31~2022/1/13" and "2022/1/10~2022/1/14" two combinations.
How to use SAS to calculate like this?
Many thanks.

[image: Sorry that just learn SAS. So, I only know how to use Excel do the calculation with small data sets. I need to do the calculation with a large data set ,but Excel can't perform it.]

Comment: Please post your data as text, not images. To work with your data we'd have to type it out. Please refer to posting guidelines here [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just post the data as table format.

Comment: In the future please post whatever you've tried as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a SQL method where you merge the data with itself, linking to the D record.
Filter for the date intervals and aggregate by the episode defined by the first four variables.

```
data have;
    infile cards dlm='09'x truncover;
    input ID $  GET_DRUG $  HOSP $  DATE : yymmdd10.    QTY;
    format date date9.;
    cards;
A   H111    H111    2021/12/31  3
A   H112    H112    2022/1/10   4
A   H110    H110    2022/1/13   5
A   D110    H110    2022/1/14   6
A   D111    H110    2022/1/16   3
A   H112    H112    2022/1/23   4
A   D113    H110    2022/1/30   5
A   D114    H110    2022/2/13   5
;
    ;
    ;;
run;

proc sql;
    create table merged as select a.id, a.get_drug, a.hosp, a.date, 
        /*count number of distinct hospitals*/
        count(distinct b.hosp) as num_distinct_hospitals, /*sum quantity*/
        sum(b.qty) as sum_qty 
        from have as a left join have as b
        /*join on same id*/
        on a.id=b.id
        /*date <15 - note that boundaries are included*/
        and b.date between a.date-14 and a.date
        /*do not join on same drug, may need to tweak this*/
        and a.get_drug ne b.get_drug
        /*use drugs that start as D for the first table*/
        where substr(a.get_drug, 1, 1)='D'
        /*group results by episode - may be useful to create an episode ID instead to simplify merge*/
        group by a.id, a.get_drug, a.hosp, a.date;
quit;

proc sql;
create table want as
select count(*) as result
from merged
where num_distinct_hospitals>=2 and sum_qty >= 10;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to get the result.
Here is one solution with the following steps:

1. Sort your data by ID and descending date.
2. Use a data step with first.ID and retain statements in order to find the first row for an ID group and to keep the values of the "D" row. Additionally check that the first row of an ID group is a "D" row.
3. In the data step you then go through the data and count the distinct HOSP values and calculate the difference of dates.
4. You can then count the number of cases with your final condition.

Hope, I understood your task correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just post the data as table format.